# Map winkey + D (show desktop shortcut) to specific monitor or screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, shortcuts

I'm using the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> a lot, becuase it's very useful for quickly minimizing all windows. Recently, I got a notebook and a monitor. I mainly work on the screen, and the laptop is only for outlook. When I use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> it minimizes all windows, but I want only to minimize the windows on the monitor, and keep outlook on the notebook.

Is there a way to map the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> action to the primary monitor?

Comment: You are missing an important detail...Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Oh snap. I'm using Windows 7